# How to uninstall Google Play Store with adb

Tags: android, adb

I used ADB to access Android apps, but I can't find which of them is the Play Store.

This is my entire Galaxy S7 app.(8.0)

```html
package:com.google.android.ext.services
package:com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox
package:com.google.android.apps.googleassistant
package:com.google.android.onetimeinitializer
package:com.google.android.ext.shared
package:com.google.android.configupdater
package:com.google.android.gm
package:com.google.android.setupwizard
package:com.google.android.music
package:com.google.android.apps.docs
package:com.google.android.apps.maps
package:com.google.android.webview
package:com.google.android.syncadapters.contacts
package:com.google.android.packageinstaller
package:com.google.android.gms
package:com.google.android.gsf
package:com.google.android.tts
package:com.google.android.partnersetup
package:com.google.android.videos
package:com.google.chromeremotedesktop
package:com.google.android.feedback
package:com.google.android.printservice.recommendation
package:com.google.android.apps.photos
package:com.google.android.syncadapters.calendar
package:com.google.android.apps.translate
package:com.google.android.backuptransport
package:com.google.android.apps.books
package:com.google.android.talk
```

This is part of the list.

Answer (score 3):

You can get the PlayStore package name and try to uninstall

**com.android.vending**

> Note: Some devices you cannot delete unless you have root permission also it's not recommended